# Why doesn't the following Javascript code (to set CSS style) work?

Tags: javascript, css

I'm trying to set the CSS style of an object with the following:

```
document.getElementById(obj).style='font-weight:bold; color:#333;';
```

but it's not working. Does anyone have any idea why?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You need to set the underlying `cssText` of the style as folows:

```
document.getElementById('xx').style.cssText='font-weight:bold; color:#333;';
```

Comment: I know a lot, but I never knew you could set cssText much the same way as innerHTML works. Nice to know.

Comment: Just wanted to add that this will reset any other styles you have associated with your element xx.

Comment: AFAIK only IE needs this syntax, all other browsers work by just setting the .style value.

Answer (score 8):

you can separate

```
document.getElementById(obj).style.fontWeight='bold';
document.getElementById(obj).style.color='#333';
```

Comment: The property is fontWeight, not font-weight. You can't have hyphens in a script identifier.

Answer (score 0):

Document's style property is a object, please reference [HTML DOM Style Object](http://www.w3schools.com/HTMLDOM/dom_obj_style.asp) on W3school